# JavaScript regex group targeting

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to catch word in some standard string (link id actually), but not to catch all string.

This

```
(?:color_form_submit_)(\w+)
```

works in ruby and catches `yellow` in `color_form_submit_yellow`

But in JS it seems to catch all string, I can't figure out why.

Comment: Show your code, what it produces and what you expect instead.

Comment: `'color_form_submit_yellow'.match(/color_form_submit_(\w+)/)[1]`

Comment: @Jack: and if it doesn't match?

Comment: @thg435 Then you get a big fat error.

Comment: @Jack: no, _you_ get an error. My code will work just fine.

Comment: @thg435 And such fine code you write indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wanted to achieve it one regex just for elegance

If you want elegance, then you could try something like this

```
var str = 'color_form_submit_yellow',
    reg = /color_form_submit_(\w+)/;

(str.match(reg) || [])[1]; // "yellow"
```

and you also have

```
('fail'.match(reg) || [])[1]; // undefined
```

This works because

```
[1, 2, 3] || []; // [1, 2, 3]
null      || []; // []
array[1] === (array)[1];
```

Comment: @Jack it's undeleted; see [**this comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043827/#comment24640982_17044150) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, JS doesn't support lookbehinds and failed `match` returns null, not an empty array. So the only way to do that in one expression, without `if` conditions, is something like

```
color = (str.match(/color_form_submit_(\w+)/) || []).pop()
```

Example:

```
> ("color_form_submit_black".match(/color_form_submit_(\w+)/) || []).pop()
"black"
> ("foo bar".match(/color_form_submit_(\w+)/) || []).pop()
undefined
```

The advantage of this construct compared to the `if` statement is that it can be used in an expression context, for example, in a function call:

```
 myRegex = /color_form_submit_(\w+)/
 showColor((myLabel.match(myRegex) || []).pop())
```

Comment: +1, didn't see this. You could also use `[1]` instead of `.pop()`, which is what I did in my (now deleted) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly look for the match to the first capturing group:

```
var myregexp = /color_form_submit_(\w+)/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
}
```

Comment: yeath, I knew I can do that, but I wanted to achieve it one regex just for elegance)

Comment: @JoeHalfFace: Sorry, no. Other regex flavors would allow `(?<color_form_submit_)\w+`, but not JavaScript.

Comment: @JoeHalfFace This *is* only one regex, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = string.match(/color_form_submit_(\w+)/);
match && match[1];
```

would be the shortest ([unnecessarily obfuscated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17044001/1047823)) way you can get in javascript.

Comment: sorry, but this is not "the shortest".

Comment: @thg435 shortest "readable" version:-p Also performance wise it is very arguable whether calling an array constructor just to pop a non existing value from it just to save one line is a good option. I don't know if you ever worked in a huge project, but your coworkers surely would kill you for this code when just one short line does the same in a far more obvious way.

Comment: Can be. Still, calling this solution "the shortest" is incorrect. And it's not about "saving one line". @Paul's  and mine solutions can be used in expression contexts, i.e. in a function call, yours - not.

Comment: @thg435 edited my answer to give you credit ^_^ But congrats, you nearly won the golf contest;)

Comment: @thg435 I only posted my answer because I didn't read yours properly first. It is now deleted, but hey if you're happy for it to re appear I don't mind pressing undelete ^^

Comment: @Christoph: I find it quite disappointing that you've resorted to a personal attack on me in this discussion. This is not something I'm happy to see here on SO.

Comment: @thg435 to be honest, I'm just jealous I couldn't figure out such a beautiful way to tackle this problem... So consider my link to your answer as confession of the superiority of your answer. +1!